# Adafruit audio FX mini and 2.5W amplifier

Tags: amplifier, sound

I am connecting [Adafruit's Audio FX Mini](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-audio-fx-sound-board/overview) board to a [small Adafruit's amplifier](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2130). In order to save some power when the sound board is not outputting any sound, I wanted to connect [ACT pin of the sound board](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-audio-fx-sound-board/pinouts) with SD (shutdown) pin of the amp ([PDF](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/PAM8302A.pdf)).

But if I connect directly these two pins, I seem to get completely opposite result, the background buzz (which is also normally heard) is heard when the sound is not played, and the sound goes off completely when the board is playing something.

Am I missing something? Should I invert ACT? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the datasheet of the PAM8302 you can see that pin 1 is called SD but note that the pin is actually called S̅D̅ <= Note the overbar

The overbar means that the pin is **active low**, also see the drawing on page 2. You need to make S̅D̅ = 0 for shutdown.

On the PCB containing the PAM8302 SD is actually marked wrongly. I do not see a transistor on the PCB (which could invert the signal and make "SD" correct) so the SD goes straight into the chip, making it a not(SD).

So yes, you need to invert the ACT signal.

The simplest way to do that is by using an NPN or a NMOS, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqjdCS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could also use a CMOS logic chip with gates that can also work as an inverter like the HEF4011.